# Getting random numbers on vector operation c++

Tags: c++, vector

I'm getting weird numbers as output in this code :

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <vector> 

int main(){

    std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec = {{0,1},{2,3}};
    
    vec.push_back({4,5});
    vec.push_back({5,6});

    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++){
        for (int i2 = 0; i2 < vec.size(); i2++){
            std::cout << vec[i][i2] << std::endl; 
        }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

It's returning to me:

```
0
1
1280136264
0
2
3
347673833
38962
4
5
297276653
134256690
5
6
280499436
268474418
```

I just want to know how to do it properly, and why I'm getting these numbers.

Comment: `std::cout << vec[i][i2] << std::endl;` Replace that with this: `std::cout << vec.at(i).at(i2) << std::endl;` -- Now your program will terminate with an [std::out_of_range](https://godbolt.org/z/ohf6PK8oz) exception, which basically explains what is going on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output you are seeing is due to **undefined behavior** in your code.

The outer `vector` object has 4 inner `vector<int>` objects added to it. Each of those inner `vector<int>` objects is holding 2 `int` values.

Your inner `for` loop is going *out of bounds* of the inner `vector<int>` objects, by trying to access 4 `int` values when there are only 2 `int` values available.

In your inner `for` loop, you need to change `vec.size()` to `vec[i].size()` instead, eg:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <vector> 

int main(){

    std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec = {{0,1},{2,3}};
    
    vec.push_back({4,5});
    vec.push_back({5,6});

    for (size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i){
        for (size_t i2 = 0; i2 < vec[i].size(); ++i2){
            std::cout << vec[i][i2] << std::endl; 
        }
        /* alternatively:
        auto &vec2 = vec[i];
        for (size_t i2 = 0; i2 < vec2.size(); ++i2){
            std::cout << vec2[i2] << std::endl; 
        }
        */
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/CXq5xB)

That being said, a safer way to code this is to use [range-for loops](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) instead, eg:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <vector> 

int main(){

    std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec = {{0,1},{2,3}};
    
    vec.push_back({4,5});
    vec.push_back({5,6});

    for (auto &vec2 : vec){
        for (auto value : vec2){
            std::cout << value << std::endl; 
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/WH6r4T)

Comment: Even better, use range-based `for`-loops, as that would have made it much harder to make OP's mistake.